# Change font size in Google App Maker code editor

Tags: css, font-size, google-app-maker, code-editor

I want to share with you a great tip for Google App Maker code editor.

As you know when you zoom-in browser screen to make font size bigger, it makes all elements bigger and this make the editor smaller.

So with this tip, we will increase font-size of the code editor only.

You can see the photos before and after changes.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcRO4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5kz6.png
```

Steps:

1. Install browser extension > Live editor for CSS, Less & Sass - Magic CSS
2. Within App Maker page, open extension and add the below css code:

   ```
     .CodeMirror-code{
     font-size: 3.5em;
     line-height: 1.5;
     }

     .CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper{
     margin-left:-20px;
     }
   ```
3. Enable extension option (Apply styles automatically).
4. Change CSS code as you like and enjoy.
5. You can activate and deactivate css code any time from extension

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not a question.